# Calculation of expected_value in SHAP explanations of XGBoost Classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, xgboost, shap

How do we make sense of SHAP `explainer.expected_value`? Why is it not the same with `y_train.mean()` after sigmoid transformation?

Below is a summary of the code for quick reference. Full code available in this notebook: https://github.com/MenaWANG/ML_toy_examples/blob/main/explain%20models/shap_XGB_classification.ipynb

```
model = xgb.XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
explainer = shap.Explainer(model)
shap_test = explainer(X_test)
shap_df = pd.DataFrame(shap_test.values)

#For each case, if we add up shap values across all features plus the expected value, we can get the margin for that case, which then can be transformed to return the predicted prob for that case:
np.isclose(model.predict(X_test, output_margin=True),explainer.expected_value + shap_df.sum(axis=1))
#True
```

But why isn't the below true? Why after sigmoid transformation, the `explainer.expected_value` is not the same with `y_train.mean()` for XGBoost classifiers?

```
expit(explainer.expected_value) == y_train.mean()
#False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SHAP` is guaranteed to be additive in raw space (logits). To understand why additivity in raw scores doesn't extend to additivity in class predictions you may think for a while why `exp(x+y) != exp(x) + exp(y)`

**Re: Just keen to understand how was explainer.expected_value calculated for XGBoost classifier. Do you happen to know?**

As I stated in comments expected value comes either from the model trees or from your data.

Let's try reproducible:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import xgboost
import shap

X, y = shap.datasets.adult()
X_display, y_display = shap.datasets.adult(display=True)

# create a train/test split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=7)
d_train = xgboost.DMatrix(X_train, label=y_train)
d_test = xgboost.DMatrix(X_test, label=y_test)

params = {
    "eta": 0.01,
    "objective": "binary:logistic",
    "subsample": 0.5,
    "base_score": np.mean(y_train),
    "eval_metric": "logloss",
}
model = xgboost.train(
    params,
    d_train,
    num_boost_round=5000,
    evals=[(d_test, "test")],
    verbose_eval=100,
    early_stopping_rounds=20,
)
```

### Case 1. No data available, trees only.

```
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
ev_trees = explainer.expected_value[0]

from shap.explainers._tree import XGBTreeModelLoader

xgb_loader = XGBTreeModelLoader(model)
ts = xgb_loader.get_trees()

v = []
for t in ts:
    v.append(t.values[0][0])
sv = sum(v)

import struct
from scipy.special import logit
size = struct.calcsize('f')
buffer = model.save_raw().lstrip(b'binf')
v = struct.unpack('f', buffer[0:0+size])[0]
# if objective "binary:logistic" or "reg:logistic" 
bv = logit(v)

ev_trees_raw = sv+bv

np.isclose(ev_trees, ev_trees_raw)
```

---

```
True
```

### Case 2. Background data set supplied.

```
background = X_train[:100]

explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model, background)
ev_background = explainer.expected_value
```

Take a note that:

```
np.isclose(ev_trees, ev_background)
```

---

```
False
```

but

```
d_train_background = xgboost.DMatrix(background, y_train[:100])
preds = model.predict(d_train_background, pred_contribs = True)

np.isclose(ev_background, preds.sum(1).mean())
```

---

```
True
```

or simply

```
output_margin = model.predict(d_train_background, output_margin=True)
np.isclose(ev_background, output_margin.mean())
```

---

```
True
```

Comment: I appreciate the response. Indeed, the test for additivity goes fine, as shown in the code posted with the question. 

Just keen to understand how was `explainer.expected_value` calculated for XGBoost classifier. Do you happen to know? Thanks again! :)

(BTW, the `explainer.expected_value` for RandomForestClassifier() is y_train.mean(), code here: https://github.com/MenaWANG/ML_toy_examples/blob/main/explain%20models/shap_basic_RF_classification.ipynb  I find these differences very interesting)

Comment: Expected values are average of raw scores over background data set or supplied trees (if no background dataset is supplied)

Comment: Good stuff! Thank you so much for the detailed explanation.